# How to get on the key of the parent from his child in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to take the name of the parent I highlight with the yellow
[image: I want to take the name of the parent I highlight with the yellow]

```
let postref = fire.database().ref('users/').orderByKey().limitToLast(100);
    postref.on('child_added', snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(childsnapshot => {
            let author = snapshot.key;
            childsnapshot.forEach(result => {
                let finaly = {text: result.val(), key: result.key , author: toString(author)}
                this.setState({posts: [finaly].concat(this.state.posts)})
            })
        })
    })

    postref.on('child_changed', snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(childsnapshot => {
            let author = snapshot.key;
            childsnapshot.forEach(result => {
                let finaly = {text: result.val(), key: result.key , author: toString(author)  }
                this.setState({posts: [finaly].concat(this.state.posts)})
            })
        })
    })
```

This is where I show all Item from the database , but posts.author show object undefined

```
<Item.Group>
    {
        this.state.posts.map(posts =>
            <Item key={posts.key} author={posts.author}color="red">
                <Item.Image size='tiny'
                            src='https://turnkeyit.co.uk/assets/img/Prose-Icon-(Blog).png'/>

                <Item.Content>
                    <Item.Header>Titolo</Item.Header>
                    <Item.Meta>Pubblicato alle /gg/mm/yy</Item.Meta>
                    <Item.Description>
                        {posts.text} {posts.key}
                    </Item.Description>
                    <Item.Extra>
                        <Button color="blue" floated='right'
                               onClick={this.GetPost.bind(posts.key)}> Rivelati <Icon
                            name='heart'/> </Button>
                    </Item.Extra>
                </Item.Content>
            </Item>
        )
    }
</Item.Group>
```

And this is the funcition i call for show the uid

```
GetPost(data){
    alert(data)
}
```

With this code, I take the value of posts of all Users, but I want to make a button to take the id from the user who makes the post. How can I get the parents key?

Comment: `snapshot.key`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it dosen't work , it return undefined

Comment: That seems weird. Can you show the updated code in your question?

Comment: Also note that I think your inner loop is missing the `posts` node in the snapshot: childsnapshot.child("posts").forEach(result => {`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i updated all

Comment: Sorry, there are too many moving pieces here. If you `console.log(snapshot.key)` insde `on("child_added"` it should log `6tfT7...Jp82`. Doesn't it do that?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes it work with console.log , but in the jsx don't work , it show undefined , why?

Comment: **maybe this can help** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835615/firebase-get-immediate-parent-of-a-child-with-specific-value