# Firebase, get immediate parent of a child with specific value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an ios app with firebase backend. As users register, user node is created in firebase under which there are different children like email, name, avatar etc. What I am doing is that I am searching for some email in user nodes and if I find that email in some node, I want to get its parent key i.e -Ksdd23d2djhsdgjhs. See the image: [image]

I want to get the value with upper arrow if the email matches with the one I have.

I have an email address and I am searching through all of the children in user node and then further check inside the to compare the email with the one I have. If email matches, I want to get its parent node like in the image it is Dn2LUAwdolg..... .

I can get the first node under user node. Assume that the node Dn2LU.. shown in picture is at some unknown position and I have to search all users to get its name if it's email child value matches with the one I am comparing it with.

Hope it's clear now

Comment: you get first element from user of 0

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far and what is not working. Your question is its current state is too broad and clearly lacks research effort.

Comment: let me add more in there.

Comment: @JacobKaif add __code__ that you have written, that is what's missing from your question... If you don't even know where to start, have a look at some Firebase tutorials.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is documented here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#equalTo

I am no IOS developer, but I here is a JS example:

```
// Find all users which match the child node email.
var ref = firebase.database().ref('user');
ref.orderByChild('email').equalTo('wal@aol.com').on("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach((function(child) { console.log(child.key) }); 
});
```

Tthe snapshot contains the whole node, but snapshot.key will return the node key (in your example: Dn2LUAwdolg...)

Comment: That `console.log()` will always log `user`. You'll either want to listen for `on("child_added"`, or loop over the child nodes `snapshot.forEach((function(child) { console.log(child.key); })`

Comment: Thanks a lot @André.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen you were right, thanks for pointing this out, I will edit my answer :)

Answer (score 10):

you can grab the reference from the snapshot using `.ref` and then grab the parent of the reference using `.parent` on the child's reference then use `.key` to grab the key of that reference which will be the parent key in your example: `Dn2LUAwdolgf6HCn11UiSihejty1`

**So we have for example on the snapshot for avata**

```
snapshot.ref.parent.key
```

**which will equal in your case**

```
Dn2LUAwdolgf6HCn11UiSihejty1
```

Answer (score 2):

I am answering my question but i will upvote @André's answer which helped me accomplish what i wanted. I am posting here the Swift 3.0 code i wrote while considering André's code.

```
        let idtosearch = email
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("user")
        ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "email").queryEqual(toValue: idtosearch).observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            print("\(snapshot.key)")
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Well in my case I have other UID's under the UID needed that to load my friendship List:

[image]

For that, I have created this method

```
class func downloadAllFriendList(UserID:String, completion: @escaping (UserSimplifiedCredentials?) -> Swift.Void) {
    var ref = Database.database().reference().child("Friendship").child(UserID).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        print("the child parent id is +++++++> \(snapshot.key)")
    })

}
```