# There is any fuction, in adroid studios and in firebase realtime database, to get the the name of a parameter that some specific data is child of?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I dont know how to exlpain it properly, but In my android studio project, I have the value of some specific data of my Firebase realtime database, and I want to know the name of the parameter that this data is child of,

[image]

Like i have value of this camp called "nomeProf" and I want to get the name of this "teste" parameter, by searching in the database using this value of "nomeProf"

there is any way of doing so ?

Comment: do you want to get `nomeProf` or `teste`?

Comment: `"teste" : "nomeProf"` is this how your database looks ? where KEY = teste & VALUE = nomeProf and you want to search the KEY with VALUE. this is what you're asking, right ?

Comment: This question is answered already for iOS! you can get reference from here
Check the link below [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835615/firebase-get-immediate-parent-of-a-child-with-specific-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835615/firebase-get-immediate-parent-of-a-child-with-specific-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

reference.orderByChild("nomeProf").equalTo("glagla").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        String teste = datas.getKey();
    }
 }
   @Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { 
     throw databaseError.toException(); 
    }
 });
```

First add the reference to the root node, then add a query to search the database based on the value of `nomeProf` and retrieve the `key` which is `teste`.

Comment: Please never leave `onCancelled` empty, as it hides potential errors. The minimal implement should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Comment: Thanks Peter! And of course: also thanks for continuing to help fellow Firebase devs.